# I want to disable edit form fields, it includes people picker filed

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm working to disable Edit form with all the fields except one drop field, which again link to hide / show script based on dropdown selected value. i have the below code to disable edit form fields, everything is working but people picker and date column is not working. any correction would be really appreciated. Thank you

````
<script src="/sites/XXXXXX/XXXXX/SiteAssets/jquery.min%20-%20disable%20edit%20options.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Update only the Opportunity Status or Proposal Status");
$(function() {

  $("div[title='Person']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("Select[title='Col1']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("Select[title='Col2']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("Select[title='Col3']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("Select[title='Col4']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("Select[title='Col5']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("input[title='Col6']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}); 
 </script>```
````

Comment: Where's the HTML for the form fields?

Comment: Its working well for the fields in SharePoint form except for People picker / person or group column and Calendar filed. any assistance of the code for people picker and calendar would help.

Comment: `div` elements can't be disabled. But half your code is missing, beyond that it's not possible to offer much more help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following code to disable people and date column.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //disable peopel column
            $(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").css({ 'display': 'none' });
            $(".sp-peoplepicker-editorInput").css({ 'display': 'none' });
            //disable date column
            $("input[title='date']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("img[id^='date']").closest("a").removeAttr("onclick");
        });
    </script>
```

Updated:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Amos_MSFT disable for Date field is working fine but people picker field is not working yet. any help would be appreciated. this is to update you, i have 3 people picker fields here to disable for editing.

Comment: People picker fields are disabled in my environment.We can not change the value in people picker field.Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise to fix html DOM using jquery or similar. There are proper ways to reach your goal.

Instead, I think you should consider either of the following :

1. Fix the `ShowInEditForm` property of the field, to completely remove the field from the edit form (there are a few other `ShowIn****` that might interest you)
2. Use CSR (Client Side Rendering) to create a readonly experience for the field. For the latter, you can try somthing like this (not tested, from memory):

```
(function () {
  var readOnlyField = function (ctx) {
      
      return '<div >' + ctx.CurrentItem.YourField + '</div>';
   }

  var overrides = {
      Templates: {
          'Fields': {
              'YourField': {
                  'EditForm': readOnlyField,
              }
          }
      }
  };

  // register the template overrides
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrides);
})();
```